# Jquery-css dropdown image list without scroll

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am using [JavaScript image combobox v3.3](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown) and i made my select dropdown list with images that looks like this [image]

How can I make this to show all 10 options without showing a scrollbar?

I'm using the following HTML:

```
<input type='number' step='0.01' name='odd'/>
<select name='bookmaker' id='bookmaker'>
  <option value='bet365' title='icons/bet365.png'></option>
  <option value='betathome' title='icons/betathome.png'></option>
  <option value='10bet' title='icons/10bet.png'></option>
  <option value='whill' title='icons/whill.png'></option>
  <option value='bwin' title='icons/bwin.png'></option>
  <option value='pinnacle' title='icons/pinnacle.png'></option>
  <option value='marathon' title='icons/marathon.png'></option>
  <option value='sportingbet' title='icons/sportingbet.png'></option>
  <option value='unibet' title='icons/unibet.png'></option>
  <option value='tipico' title='icons/tipico.png'></option>
</select>
```

And this is the jQuery code:

```
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('jQuery is now ready to be executed!');
    $('#bookmaker').msDropDown();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of this?

Answer (score 0):

try this code after populate droap down

```
$('.ddChild ddchild_ border shadow').removeAttr("height");
```

Comment: or u can increase height as per requiredment